# 6x gtx 1080ti rig rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a problem with a rig of six 1080ti.

If I render my scene with a server 1x 1080ti it takes 1h15min to complete the frame.

If I render the same scene with the rig (6x 1080ti) it takes 25min to complete the frame.

25min multiplied by the number of GPU = 25 x 6 = 150mins

1 GPU on server = 1h15min
1 GPU on rig = 2h30min

How do I have to set up the rig? I just need the same render speed(in %) between server and rig.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Im using a rig (1 computer with 6 GPU) to export instead of 6 single computers.
I just need the same render speed(in %) between server and rig

Comment: Looks like your rig is bottlenecked somewhere, maybe the CPU, system RAM or number of pci lanes is the problem. You might want to post your full system specs.

Comment: mobo: z370 prime A
ram:16gb
cpu: i8700k
HD: M.2 pro

I tried BIOS setups
Blender setups
Hardware setups

The 1070 rig (6x gpu) is working fine, each 1070 is rendering like a pc with 1080ti.

Comment: I doubt that there is much to do to change those numbers in a dramatic way. It is true that adding more GPUs will shorten rendering time, but there is definitely some overhead. To acccommodate 6GPUs you are likely using some form of GPU riser cable, that might also have some impact on the performance. Try a test using only the GPUs that are connected directly to the motherboard and see if there is a performance change

Comment: One gpu connected to the mobo needs the same time to render of one gpu connected with a riser cable.
The problem comes only when i add new gpu cards.. 

Is it possible that the CPU is not able to use correctly more than one 1080ti?

I will try overclocking the CPU

Comment: CPU overclock doesn't work